# How to get C11 threads (and other) man pages on linux system

Tags: c, linux, libc, c11, manpage

I can't find manual pages for any of the functions declared in `threads.h` added in C11.
There is good documentation for them in https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/11
and in the glibc docs, however I would like to access information through man pages,
like most libc functions are available (e.g `man printf`).

Where can I find?

Comment: I would guess they just don't exist, from looking at the [repo where they come from](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/docs/man-pages/man-pages.git/tree/man3?h=man-pages-6.05.y)

Comment: C11 threads are simple wrappers over the pthread interfaces, you can use `man -k pthread` or `apropos pthread` to get the list of functions.

Comment: @DavidRanieri That doesn't help, the interface is not the same. Besides, threads are just an example of C11 functions that lack man pages which it happens that I'm working with, so even if I wanted to use pthreads the question would remain.

Comment: There is a list of [missing pan pages](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/missing_pages.html), which includes some (but not all) of the C11 thread functions. Feel free you write them yourself and submit upstream!

Comment: C11 threads weren't a big success, it had a bigger impact on C++. I guess thread support simply arrived far too late for anyone to care, since OS-specific threads had already become de facto standard.

Answer (score 0):

References for threads library functions are not well defined. Work seems needed to be done.  You are right.